# Convert date format in CSV using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have two CSV file with 50 column and more than 10K row. There is a column having date-time value. In some records it is 01/18/2013 18:16:32 and some records is 16/01/2014 17:32.

What I want to convert the column data like this: `01/18/2013 18:16`. I want to remove seconds value. I want to do it by PowerShell script.

Sample data:

```
10/1/2014 13:18
10/1/2014 13:21
15/01/2014  12:03:19
15/01/2014  17:39:27
15/01/2014  18:29:44
17/01/2014  13:33:59
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not going to convert to a sane date format anyway, you can just do a regex replace of that column:

```
Import-Csv foo.csv |
  ForEach-Object {
    $_.Date = $_.Date -replace '(\d+:\d+):\d+', '$1'
  } |
  Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation foo-new.csv
```

You could also go the route of using date parsing, but that's probably a bit slower:

```
Import-Csv foo.csv |
  ForEach-Object {
    $_.Date = [datetime]::Parse($_.Date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm')
  } |
  Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation foo-new.csv
```

If you're sure that there are no other timestamps or anything that could look like it elsewhere, you can also just replace everything that looks like it without even parsing as CSV:

```
$csv = Get-Content foo.csv -ReadCount 0
$csv = $csv -replace '(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}):\d{2}', '$1'
$csv | Out-File foo-new.csv
```

Comment: @Joey: thanks for your reply. I want to go with option two. one question i have is my contain other column as well. It will affect them or not. I have uploaded the sample data in question.

Comment: I am getting this error while running second option. Exception calling "Parse" with "1" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: That's because the date format in there doesn't match your locale. You have to use `ParseExact` and specify the format. Note also that your sample data doesn't match the format you gave earlier in the question.

Comment: Thanks Joey. I will do parseExact to get the data.